# Android: Toolbar getting scrolled when only trying to scroll text view

Tags: android

Android: I have created a toolbar using Material science and I am using it in my activity. My activity  contains a text view and 2 Buttons(Prev and Next). The text is multiline so I am using Scrollview,But the issue is when by adding scrollview my toolbar is also getting hidden when I scroll the Text. I understand this as I am included the toolbar inside the scrollview so it is also getting scrolled. But I only want to scroll my text not my toolbar and wants to always show my toolbar at the top. Please look at my xml file and let me know the soln.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Singleton"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#212121"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/designPrimaryBackgroundColor"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/single_string"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using          to add the customized toolbar. Please let me know how can I include the toolbar in this file so that it wont get scrolled when I scrolled the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a LinearLayout as the main parent and have the toolbar (include) as the first child and the ScrollView as the second child

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation:vertical >

    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        ...
```

Comment: If it is so, please mark the answer as the solution. Thank you